# Fetching data from one db and saving it in another in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, json, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an app that uses SQLite now. And now I am changing it to PostgreSQL. The table structure is changed. But I want to import the data from the previous db to the new one.

How can I fetch the data and save it in the new table?

I tried few things like getting the json from url and save the data in the table but I have problems in parsing the json string. So I am confused on how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

You can export the data from sqlite into a sql file with a method in your model. 
This way you can change table column names since table structure changed.

sql_export method in `app/models/user.rb`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.sql_export
    filecontent = ""
    User.all.each do |user|
      filecontent << "INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES ('#{user.email}','#{user.password}');"
    end
    File.open("tmp/export.sql", "w+") do |f|
     f.write(filecontent)
    end
end
```

Fire up rails console and run the method (**Make sure that you are running in the environment that it connects to sqlite database**):

```
$> rails c
$ irb> User.sql_export
```

It basically read all data from your database and generate insert statements and write to `tmp/export.sql` file.

Then import the sql file to your postgresql

```
psql databasename < tmp/export
```

Answer (score 0):

I have now found a way to parse the json data as follows

```
url = "http://samplesite/export_data.json"
        resp = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(url))
        data = resp.body
        post_data = JSON.parse(data)
        post_data.each do |value|
           u = Model.new
           u.field = value['name']
           u.save
        end
```

This can be used to take data from table and can be saved into another table accordingly.